# Download Latest file

Tags: powershell

I have a network folder with lots of files. I need to grab the latest file that starts with 'billings' and ends in 'csv'

This script works fine if I specify the exact file to download

```
# Source URL
$url = "\\10.50.11.41\APFMFN\billingsTest.csv "

# Destination file
$dest = "\\usw2gpapp01\Bron_GPguy\SmartConnect\testfiles-$(get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmmss).csv"

# Download the file
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $dest
```

How do I modify the source url to include latest file? Where do I specify getchilditem (if that is what I need)?

I think I need to use getchild item property but couldn't get the syntax correct....

Comment: Didn't work - I modified as follows:  # Source URL
$url = Get-ChildItem "\\10.50.11.41\APFMFN\" -Filter *.csv 

# Destation file
$dest = "\\usw2gpapp01\Bron_GPguy\SmartConnect\testfiles-$(get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmmss).csv"

# Download the file
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $dest

Comment: Got this message PS C:\Users\Bron.Tamulis> D:\Bron_GPguy\SmartConnect\SimpleDowloadWorks.ps1
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Uri' required by parameter 'Uri'. 
Specified method is not supported.
At D:\Bron_GPguy\SmartConnect\SimpleDowloadWorks.ps1:8 char:24
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $dest
+                        ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, I though you were querying fileshare hence why I asked about trying with `Get-ChildItem`, my bad. So, in order for us to help you, I guess you would need to show us how can you get the available list of files on `10.50.11.41\APFMFN`

Comment: your posted code shows that you are specifying the datestamp out to the _then-current second_ ... so, are you SURE that the file has that exact timestamp?

Comment: Maybe Santiago already asked this, but why the need for `Invoke-WebRequest` ? Can't you target the source and destination shares directly?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I actually have the source URL working fine by using Get ChildItem. This works great - # Source URL
$url = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\10.50.11.41\APFMFN\" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending)[0].FullName

Comment: Reason for using Invoke-WebRequest - no particular reason - I googled for examples and decided to try it and it works even though I am not going outside the internal network to grab the file.

Comment: Please consider this closed. Santiago put me on right path by using Get ChildItem